# npm run causes "The syntax of the command is incorrect"

Tags: npm

In a node project I have the following "build" task:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "rm -rf build/ && rm -rf app/ && prettier --write source/ && tsc && cp -r ../app/dist/. ./build/app && mkdir build/app/config"
}
```

This runs fine on MacOS but when running on windows I use the [git bash](https://gitforwindows.org) to run it because with PowerShell `rm` fails. But when running `npm run` from the git bash I get an error:

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

But when I run each command individually or execute just

```
rm -rf build/ && rm -rf addin/ && prettier --write source/ && tsc && cp -r ../addin/dist/. ./build/addin && mkdir build/addin/config
```

directly all together in the bash it seems all to work.

What could could be the issue? Why doesn't it work through `npm run build` in git bash on Windows?